# Using answers package in macros

Tags: macros, external-files, answers

I am compiling a set of problems for my students with hints, and using the `answers` package for that.

The goal would be to have the problems and hints grouped by exercise session, but still within the same file.
For this I took the example file from the `answers` package ([here in §4](https://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/answers/answers.pdf)), but spread the steps out in 3 macros:

- `\SHEET` opens the solution file
- `\exercise` would print the exercise and write the hint into the external temp file
- `\HINT` would read the external file and print

However the macros don't seem to work; the temporary file should only contain the hints one after another, however it seems latex does not stop there and continues to write lines of source code to the file, which makes it unreadable.

Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{hnt}{Hint for Exercise}{ans}
\newtheorem{exr}{Exercise}

\newcommand{\SHEET}{
\stepcounter{lecturecounter}
\section*{Sheet \arabic{lecturecounter}}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}
}

\newcommand{\HINT}{
\Closesolutionfile{ans}
\section*{Hints for Sheet \arabic{lecturecounter}}
\input{ans\arabic{lecturecounter}}
}

\newcommand{\exercise}[2]{
\begin{exr}
#1
\begin{hnt}
#2
\end{hnt}
\end{exr}
}

\newcounter{lecturecounter}

\begin{document}

\SHEET

\exercise{Exercise}{Hint}
\exercise{Exercise}{Hint}
\exercise{Exercise}{Hint}

\HINT

\SHEET

\exercise{Exercise}{Hint}
\exercise{Exercise}{Hint}
\exercise{Exercise}{Hint}

\HINT

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `exsheets` package, it is possible.

If anyone is interested, here is my complete solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{exsheets}

\printsolutions[section]
\SetupExSheets{counter-within=section}
\DeclareTranslation{English}{exsheets-question-name}{Exercise}
\DeclareTranslation{English}{exsheets-solution-name}{Hint for Exercise}

\newcounter{lecturecounter}

\newcommand{\SHEET}[1]{
\section{#1}
\stepcounter{lecturecounter}
}

\newcommand{\HINT}{
\large{Hints for Sheet \arabic{lecturecounter}} \\
\printsolutions[section]
}

\newcommand{\exercise}[2]{
\begin{question}
#1
\end{question}
\def\temp{#2}\ifx\temp\empty
\else
\begin{solution}
#2
\end{solution}
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\SHEET{Title}

\exercise{Exercise}{Hint}
\exercise{Exercise}{Hint}

\HINT
    
\SHEET{Title}

\exercise{Exercise}{Hint}
\exercise{Exercise}{Hint}

\HINT

\end{document}
```